# JavaScript: When we can omit curly brackets?

Tags: javascript

I noticed today that looping of JavaScript object can be done using less curly brackets.

For instance, the normal way of doing things:

```
// The normal way
var foo = {
    bar: 1
};

for(var key in foo) {  
    if(foo.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(foo[key]); // prints out 1
    }
}
```

The alternative, by dropping out extra `{ ... }` and it still works:

```
// The alternative
var foo = {
    bar: 1
};

for(var key in foo) if(foo.hasOwnProperty(key)) { // <-- see :)
    console.log(foo[key]); // prints out 1
}
```

However, I am less sure why this is possible. So my question is: when curly brackets can be omitted? I got a downvote saying "too broad" so I try to emphasize that **I am not looking a million use cases**, short answer suits just fine which explains the basics.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can even omit the brackets in the for loop...pretty much anything that is just one line then you can remove the brackets

Comment: As a side note, it is advisable to always use curly brackets, as omitting them can lead to some very annoying bugs. Personally, I always use them.

Comment: @forgivenson good point, and note for downvoter. Leave a comment next time, I hate that when ppl just pass by and drops arrows. Can't read minds here.

Comment: @MaunoV.: me too dislike downvotes without comments

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can omit curly braces anytime there is only one statement.

```
for (var x in obj) {
    console.log(x);
}
```

can become

```
for (var x in obj)
    console.log(x);
```

but if you had

```
for (var x in obj) {
    console.log(x);
    console.log(x);
}
```

it would need the curly braces.

---

This is somewhat inconsistent. For example, it works for `for`, `while` and `if`, but not for `try` or `catch`. For consistency, I always use braces.

Comment: @MaunoV.: i understand my mistake,and i apologise,sorry for that

Comment: but:                                                                                                 

`for(var key in foo)                                                             
    if(foo.hasOwnProperty(key))                                         
      console.log(foo[key]);`                                                                         


can be 2 lines after the for statement

Comment: @GarisMSuero, because the `for` has one statement: `if`. That `if` has one statement too. The statements are nested.

Answer (score 5):

After a `if` or loop (`for`, `while`) you can ommit the `{` if you have only one statement after it. So

```
if (condition)
    someFunction();
```

equals to

```
if (condition) {
    someFunction();
}
```

And

```
if (condition) a(); b();
```

equals to

```
if (condition) {
    a();
}
b();
```

You can even nest that:

```
if (condition) 
    while(condition2)
        if (condition3)
            someFunction();
```

For readibility it's best (read: I prefer) to always use braces (also less prone to make programming-errors).

Comment: Thanks for the examples. Maybe the nifty way of looping object just caught me by surprise. :)

Answer (score 0):

As long  it's **one instruction** you can omit curly brackets.

```
for(var key in foo) 
    if(foo.hasOwnProperty(key))
        console.log(foo[key]); // prints out 1

for(var key in foo)
    if(foo.hasOwnProperty(key))
        for(var i=0; i<=10; i++) {  
            console.log(foo[key]); // prints out 1
            console.log(foo[key]); // prints out 1
            console.log(foo[key]); // prints out 1
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is **only one case where you can omit the curly braces** and that is **when you only have one statement after the condition**

```
if (condition) statement;
```

in your example you have omitted the curly braces from the first condition and but kept them in the second

```
if (condition)
    if (condition) { statement; }
```

**[Note]** It is possible to omit semicolons but it is considered bad programming practice.